# satchmo password_reset html format mail

Tags: django, satchmo

Ive been requested by a client that his satchmo store should send an html formatted mail when resetting his password.

Aparently satchmo or django's contrib.auth.views.password_reset sends only raw email.

How do I modify this in order to be able to send html formatted mails?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used Satchmo, but this should get you started.

First of all, subclass the `PasswordResetForm`, and override the `save` method to send an html email instead of a plain text email.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

class HTMLPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def save(self, domain_override=None, email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
             use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator, from_email=None, request=None):
        """
        Generates a one-use only link for resetting password and sends to the user
        """
        # Left as an exercise to the reader
```

You can use the [existing `PasswordResetForm`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/forms.py) as a guide. You need replace the `send_mail` call at the end with code to send html emails. The docs about [sending html emails](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types) should help.

Once you've written your form, you need to include the form in the url pattern for `password_reset`. As I said, I don't have any experience of Satchmo, but looking at the source code, I think you want to update `satchmo_store.accounts.urls`, by changing the password_reset_dict.

```
# You need to import your form, or define it in this module
from myapp.forms import HTMLPasswordResetForm

#Dictionary for authentication views
password_reset_dict = {
    'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_form.html',
    # You might want the change the email template to .html
    'email_template_name': 'registration/password_reset.txt',
    'password_reset_form': HTMLPasswordResetForm,
}

# the "from email" in password reset is problematic... it is hard coded as None
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
    (r'^password_reset/$', 'password_reset', password_reset_dict, 'auth_password_reset'),
    ...
```